# Youtube videos with Cuepoint JS

Tags: html5-video, youtube-javascript-api, popcornjs

Is there any way to handle Youtube videos with Cuepoint JS http://cuepoint.org?
Or do you know any alternative?

I tried popcorn.js but it is complex and i'd have i'd have to make a lot of changes at the Youtube player because it doesn't request HTML5 videos and so on...

And the Video.js also has problems to handle Youtube videos...

I don't want to write one skript for the normal HTML5 player and a diffrent skript Youtube player.

Answer (score 0):

[And captions/subtitles to video-js youtube playlist player](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16115808/and-captions-subtitles-to-video-js-youtube-playlist-player)

http://bestimage.x10.mx/Playlist_yt/YouTube_PlayList.html